# How to preserve the items stored in an array in Vue

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I have the code below that adds the item to the array if the checkbox is clicked. But, when I clicked a new item, the recently added item is replaced with the new one. Please see below:

```
data(){
    return{
        selected:[],
        select:true,
    }
},
```

**METHOD**

```
addMe(item){
    if(this.select == true){
        this.selected.push(item.emp_key)
    }
}
```

So if  my array (`selected`) has already a data, let's say `1`, (added when checkbox is clicked), and then I clicked item 2, item 1 is removed, replaced with `2` and so on. Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: You should try using lodash :)

Comment: @mark333...333...333 What's that?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10

Comment: @mark333...333...333 can you please give me a working sample for this? It's kinda new to me.

Comment: The approach you use seems correct, but some details are missing:

    How you define the handler for the checkbox. Can you provide the template you use?
    From your snippets, it's unclear what item variable is and what value it has. item is not defined in addMe function, is it a global variable?
    Is there any other code that may affect the value of this.selected array?

Comment: @Tim Have addressed this concern below :)

Comment: I see no reason to suggest lodash here.  As written in the question, this code works as expected; pushing onto an array *does not* replace the array in Vue or anywhere else.  There must be other code not shown here causing your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing onto an array does not replace the array.  The below is your code, with a fake incrementing ID number added to show different values pushed onto `this.selected`:

```js
Vue.component('demo', {
  template: '<div><button v-on:click="addMe({emp_key: fakeid++})">Click me</button> {{selected}} </div>',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: [],
      select: true,
      fakeid: 1
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addMe(item) {
      if (this.select == true) {
        this.selected.push(item.emp_key)
      }

    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <demo></demo>
</div>
```

Comment: you are just adding value to  fakeid but how I can achieve if fakeid is getting from server side

Comment: Essentially the same way. `addMe` would make an async server call, retrieve the value, and push to the array in its `success()` handler.  (Or if `item` is retrieved before the user clicks the addMe button, then `addMe()` would look exactly the same as it does here.)

Comment: (You may have reduced the code sample in your question too much, as it no longer demonstrates the problem you're asking for help with....)

Answer (score -1):

@ramedju try this hope it will help you

```
<script>
   var arr=[]
   export default {
      data(){
        return{
             select:true,
            }
         },
   methods:{
        add(){
            if(this.select== true){
            arr=arr.concat(item.emp_key)
           }
        console.log(arr)
    }
  }
}
```

full code which i had use during testing

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="1" v-model="select">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" @click.prevent="add()"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"> </i>Success</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  var arr=[]
  export default {
     data(){
        return{
           select:1,
          }
      },
 methods:{
        add(){
            var item="1"
            arr=arr.concat(item)
            console.log(this.select)
            console.log("arr")
           console.log(arr)
         }
      }
    }
</script>
```

result of console log

arr
["1"]
arr
["1","1"]
arr
["1","1","1"]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172007/discussion-on-answer-by-bipin-how-to-preserve-the-items-stored-in-an-array-in-vu).